# Getting data from the URL in MVC

Tags: php, url-routing

Let's say my url looks like this now - .../users/promote/21. I tried getting the id by several ways but it was unlucky. I figured out that I can use  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and just split it by '/' and take the last element but I think that there are better ways to do this. So my question is how can i get the number 21 so I can use it in the users controller?

Answer (score 0):

you should have users controller

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/users/promote?userId=21"></a>
```

set the url like this example and

```
public function promote(){
$userId= $_GET ["userId"];
var_dump($userId);
}
```

you will get the value 21

Comment: That code doesnt work. Not even a little bit, if you are not using a framework. And recommending a newbie to use a framework would be probably quite harmful. Have a downvote.

Comment: This won't work, simply because whenever i hit the button  it will redirect to  promote?userId=21 and an error will occur saying that function 'promote?userId=21' doesn't exist in Users Controller